# How do you make a cluster of cubes explode?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

How can you make a bunch of objects explode? I don't mean fracture, I just mean shoot off in random directions. I want to know how to do this for a rigid body simulation. So how can this be accomplished?

Comment: @TARDISMaker ? I don't see how this is asking for a in-depth tutorial.. If *any* kind of tutorial is considered off-topic, then this site doesn't make any sense ;)

Comment: Okay, I guess we just have different places where we draw the line. To me it still seems a bit too tutorial like for a question and answer site. I guess I'm more strict about it than I should be than.

Comment: if you ask me, explosions should be on topic either way, just cause they're so dang cool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Add Active Rigid Body Physics to your cubes.
   (I created the cubes with 3 array modifiers applied, then separated *By Loose Parts*, and finally moved the origins to the geometry.)
2. Add a force field in the middle of the stack of the cubes.
3. Increase the strength of the force field.
4. Press play or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and watch the explosion.

Quick gif showing the whole process.
[image: animated gif]

Final result
[image: animated gif]

Comment: This is very useful, but I can't get the exact effect you had. You are using Blender 2.74, right? Strength = 900 didn't seem to cut it.

Comment: Never mind. I found a strength that will work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheMinecraftMan757 make sure you have [applied the scale](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7298/5705) of the cubes.

Comment: It works but I also tried to make an explosion with particle effects. The force field is messing with the particles so is there a way around this?

Comment: GIF showing the whole process is not there.