# How do I make multiple objects explode/separate?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

As depicted in the title, I'd like to know how to make a selection of object separate at speed from each other. 
More specifically a Lego model, the concept idea is to make a Lego object (containing about 150 parts) explode but keeping each individual brick intact. If possible it would be amazing to have the explosion parts move at randomised speeds, making the result look more natural.
Thanks.

Comment: Well I have only just got into blender in the past few months, so I haven't tried a lot, as I'm no expert, and I'm not sure what half the things do.

Comment: If a lego model. Then just have each piece a separate object. Then use [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/29114/2217) method.